# Jquery: trouble in running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

okay so here is the deal,i'm a bit new to jquery and tried to make a 'welcome' that would fade IN as the page loads but it just wont work......HELP!!! anyone :) :D
html:

```
<body>
<p id="message" style="display:none;">WELCOME</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
</body>
```

init.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#message").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: Wrong js files import order?

Comment: you must change the order of loading `init.js` and `jquery.js`

Comment: HOW CAN I BE SUCH A BIG IDIOTTTTTTT!!!!! but thankx guys anyways......:D

Answer (score 2):

change order of JS files

```
<body>
<p id="message" style="display:none;">WELCOME</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>

</body>
```

Jquey.js should be loaded then only browser will recognise Jquery functions.